# How to encrypt/decrypt text on CentOs/RHEL in FIPS mode?

Tags: linux, centos, encryption, redhat-enterprise-linux

To encrypt and decrypt text I am using:

```
echo test | openssl enc -e -a -A -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -iter 1234 -k <passphrase>
echo <encrypted text> | openssl enc -d -a -A -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -iter 1234 -k <passphrase>
```

This works great, until I test it on RHEL7 (or CentOS7) system which has FIPS enabled. This is what I get as output when I try to encrypt text as indicated above:

> unknown option '-pbkdf2'

So I try it without that option, and I get:

> unknown option '-iter'

So I try it without either of those options:

```
echo test | openssl enc -e -a -A -aes-256-cbc -k <passphrase>
```

That results in this error:

> U2Fs...12:error:060800A3:digital envelope routines:EVP_DigestInit_ex:disabled for fips:digest.c:256:

So I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm open to using other tools to encrypt/decrypt text in a FIPS-compliant way.

Note: I found a potential solution on [RedHat's knowledge-base](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/176633), but it's behind a paywall. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by removing the `-pbkdf2` and `-iter` options, and specifying the message digest algorithm via `-md sha256`:

```
echo test | openssl enc -e -a -A -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -k <passphrase>
```